# Optaplanner VehicleRouting First Pick, Last drop condition

Tags: routes, optaplanner

I am new to optaplanner and am looking for a way to define Customers gender and enforce that when the route is created, No Female Customer gets picked first or dropped last. I am using incremental solver & ROAD_DISTANCE xml and have tried decreasing the hardScore in InsertCustomer and reset it back in retractCustomer. It doesn't seem to work. Please help me get through this. 
Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the VRP example, add this method in the Customer class:

```
public boolean isFemaleAndFirstOrLast() {
    return gender == FEMALE
            && (previousStandstill instanceof Vehicle
            || nextStandstill == null);
}
```

And then add a score rule to punish that

```
when
    Customer(femaleAndFirstOrLast == true)
then
    scoreHolder.add...(...);
end
```

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey! Pls let me know one more thing. In case the routing is not possible without keeping a female at last drop or first pick. The system should add a male to each vehicle dynamically, if last drop or first pick is female.

Comment: See Score calculation section to understand score weights and score levels.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is there any way to do 'femaleAndFirstOrLast' algorithm using IncrementalScoreCalculator.java file.